# Error in creating library from C file

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to call a C function defined in sample_c.c (with function declaration in sample_c.h) from a C++ code. I'm using this declaration in sample_c.h

```
extern "C" void print_c(void);
```

and this definition in sample_c.c

```
extern void print_c(void) {....}
```

and trying to generate lib which I want to link with my cpp code. I'm getting an error when trying to generate lib out of this C code.

```
gcc -c sample_c.c
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constant
```

I'm unable to rectify this. Can someone suggest where am I going wrong.

Comment: Probably the only question **ever** that is correct in using the `c` and `c++` tags at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`extern "C"` is not valid in C. To write a header that can be used for both C and C++ you have to make sure that the `extern "C"` is not visible when compiled as C:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void print_c(void);
```